# How to select range dynamically in app script spreadsheet? How to get last cell id?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google app script spreadsheet project. I want to give input to a function which will put this input value in a spreadsheet dynamically. Below is my code,

```
function setSheetValue(value,value2,value3,value4,value5){
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('********')
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
  range.setValue(value);
  var range = sheet.getRange('B1');
  range.setValue(value2);
  var range = sheet.getRange('C1');
  range.setValue(value3);
  var range = sheet.getRange('D1');
  range.setValue(value4);
  var range = sheet.getRange('E1');
  range.setValue(value5);
}
```

I have taken 4 values as input and putting this values in spreadsheet cells which I have hardcoded. So if I run again then values will get overridden. Now what I want if I add value in consider A1 in 1st run then when I run next time value will be added in A2. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: The question looks to be too broad. Please narrow it to a single question. Also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

In this answer, I would like to propose to use the method of `appendRow`. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor.

```
function setSheetValue(...values) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheetspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow([...values]);
}

// Please run this function.
function run() {
  setSheetValue("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5");
}
```

- In this case, when the function `run` is run, `"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"` are put to the next row of last row of columns "A" to "E". When you run it again, the values are appended to the next row of the previous values.

#### Note:

- `sheet` of `var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('********')` the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet. So in this case, the 1st sheet is used with `getSheets()[0]`. If you want to use this script for the specific sheet, please modify `getSheets()[0]` to `getSheetByName("Sheet1");`.

#### Reference:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)